# Trade/Win/Loss Count and Percent Profitable in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

There are some function in pine script such as:

```
closed_trades = strategy.closedtrades
win_trades    = strategy.wintrades
loss_trades   = strategy.losstrades
percent_profitable = (strategy.wintrades/strategy.closedtrades)*100
```

But without using these functions, how I can measure these parameters in pine script? I tried to code it but I could not manage. Could you please help me?

Best Regards

```
//@version=4
study("My Script",overlay=true)

ema1=ema(close,9)
ema2=ema(close,21)

buy=crossover(ema1,ema2)
sell=crossunder(ema1,ema2)

buy_price=valuewhen(buy,close,1)
sell_price=valuewhen(sell,close,1)

plot(ema1,color=color.green)
plot(ema2,color=color.red)

buy_cnt=cum(buy?1:0)
sell_cnt=cum(sell?1:0)
total_cnt = buy_cnt + sell_cnt

win_cnt = cum(buy_price>sell_price?1:0)
loss_cnt = cum(buy_price<sell_price?1:0)

f_draw_label(x,y,textline)=>
    var label Label = na
    label.delete(Label)
    Label := label.new(x, y, textline, color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white,textalign=text.align_left, style=label.style_labeldown, yloc=yloc.price, xloc=xloc.bar_time)

x = timenow
y = highest(close,50)

format_text(str) =>
    str + "\n"

txt1 = format_text(tostring(total_cnt))
txt2 = format_text(tostring(buy_cnt))
txt3 = format_text(tostring(sell_cnt))
txt4 = format_text(tostring(win_cnt + loss_cnt))
txt5 = format_text(tostring(win_cnt))
txt6 = format_text(tostring(loss_cnt))

all_txt=txt1 + txt2 + txt3 + txt4 + txt5 + txt6

f_draw_label(x,y,all_txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do your own trade management and use vars to keep track of when you enter, when you are in a trade. Save the entry level when you enter, then measure delta when you exit and update trade counts accordingly. See the [Backtesting & Trading Engine](https://www.tradingview.com/script/dYqL95JB-Backtesting-Trading-Engine-PineCoders/) for complete trade management code.